# How to create animation of vehicle moving form A to B along a route?

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, tmap, osrm

below is an example of finding route, travel time and travel distance from 'One World Trade Center, NYC' to 'Madison Square Park, NYC' using `osrm` package in R. (I learnt it from  [Road Routing in R](https://www.jla-data.net/eng/routing-in-r-context/)). The travel time here is 10.37 minutes.

I wanted to create an video for visualization.

Q. How can I create an animation of vehicle (represented by a marker) moving from 'One World Trade Center, NYC' to 'Madison Square Park, NYC' along the route ?

Ideally, we should know the speed in each road segment. But lets assume the vehicle moves non-stop at constant speed (= distance/time) between two location.

We can simply use `tmap` instead of leaflet also to create animation.

[image]

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(osrm)

# 1. One World Trade Center, NYC
# 2. Madison Square Park, NYC
adresses <- c("285 Fulton St, New York, NY 10007", 
            "11 Madison Ave, New York, NY 10010")

# geocode the two addresses & transform to {sf} data structure
data <- tidygeocoder::geo(adresses, method = "osm") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

osroute <- osrm::osrmRoute(loc = data,
                           returnclass = "sf")

summary(osroute)



library(leaflet)

leaflet(data = data) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addMarkers(label = ~address) %>% 
  addPolylines(data = osroute,
               label = "OSRM engine",
               color = "red")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to the `tmap` approach proposed by @mrhellman I offer an alternative built on `ggplot`, `ggmap` (for the basemap) and `gganimate` based workflow.

I have found the outcome of animations created via {gganimate} preferable, as {gganimate} gives me more control - such as the shadow_wake that in my opinion nicely illustrates the movement of a car along the line. If I remember correctly tmap uses gganimate under the hood.

`ggmap` does not support CartoDB basemaps - such as the Positron used above - but I have found the toner background adequate.

Note that `ggmap` does not play quite nicely with `ggplot2::geom_sf()` and I have found it easier to transform my workflow to old `ggplot2::geom_point()` approach - i.e. extract the x and y coordinates and map them via aes().

As there is only a single route to display it should be sufficient to calculate a technical variable `seq` that is used in the `transition_reveal()` to animate; this may be replaced by a time dimension if & when necessary (such as when displaying more routes with different travel time in a single animation).

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidygeocoder)
library(osrm)

# 1. One World Trade Center, NYC
# 2. Madison Square Park, NYC
adresses <- c("285 Fulton St, New York, NY 10007", 
              "11 Madison Ave, New York, NY 10010")

# geocode the two addresses & transform to {sf} data structure
data <- tidygeocoder::geo(adresses, method = "osm") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

osroute <- osrm::osrmRoute(loc = data,
                           returnclass = "sf")

# sample osroute 50 times regularly, cast to POINT, return sf (not sfc) object
osroute_sampled <- st_sample(osroute, type = 'regular', size = 50) %>%
  st_cast('POINT') %>%
  st_as_sf() 


library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap) # warning: has a naming conflict with tidygeocoder!
library(gganimate)

# ggmap does not quite like geom_sf(), 
# the "old school" geom_point will be easier to work with
osroute_xy <- osroute_sampled %>% 
  mutate(seq = 1:nrow(.),
         x = st_coordinates(.)[,"X"],
         y = st_coordinates(.)[,"Y"]) 

# basemap / the bbox depends on yer area of interest
NYC <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(-74.05, 40.68, -73.9, 40.8),
                     zoom = 13,
                     maptype = "toner-background")

# draw a map 
animation <- ggmap(NYC) + 
  geom_point(data = osroute_xy,
             aes(x = x, y = y),
             color = "red",
             size = 4) +
  theme_void() +
  transition_reveal(seq) +
  shadow_wake(wake_length = 1/6)

# create animation
gganimate::animate(animation, 
                   nframes = 2*(nrow(osroute_xy)+1), 
                   height = 800, 
                   width = 760,
                   fps = 10, 
                   renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = T))

# save animation  
gganimate::anim_save('animated_nyc.gif')
```

[image: animated map of a car in nyc]

Comment: Thank you very much @Jindra Lacko. I was wondering if you can help me build the final part of it -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908920/create-animation-of-vehicle-moving-along-a-route-with-timeline-of-events

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `{mapdeck}` approach, which gives you an interactive map (like leaflet), and animated trips, and it can easily handle thousands of trips at a time

[image]

```r
library(mapdeck)

set_token( secret::get_secret("MAPBOX") )

mapdeck(
  location = as.numeric( data[1, ]$geometry[[1]] ) ## for 'trips' you need to specify the location
  , zoom = 12
  , style = mapdeck_style("dark")
) %>%
  add_trips(
    data = sf
    , stroke_colour = "#FFFFFF" #white
    , trail_length = 12
    , animation_speed = 8
    , stroke_width = 50
  )
```

the `add_trips()` function takes an `sf` linestring object with the Z and M dimensions (z = elevation, m = time). So you can have a timestamp assocaited with each coordinate

```
library(mpadeck)
library(sfheaders)


df_route <- sfheaders::sf_to_df(osroute, fill = TRUE)

## Assume 'duration' is constant
## we want the cumulative time along the rute
df_route$cumtime <- cumsum(df_route$duration)


## and we also need a Z component.
## since we don't know the elevation, I'm setting it to '0'
df_route$elevation <- 0

## Build the 'sf' object wtih the Z and M dimensions
sf <- sfheaders::sf_linestring(
  obj = df_route
  , x = "x"
  , y = "y"
  , z = "elevation"
  , m = "cumtime"
)
```

---

The [website](https://symbolixau.github.io/mapdeck/articles/trips.html) has more details.

Comment: Thank you SymbolixAU. I was wondering if you can also look at the followup of this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908920/create-animation-of-vehicle-moving-along-a-route-with-timeline-of-events

Answer (score 3):

Sample the route (a LINESTRING) with the number of points you would like to have, then use an `lapply` function to make the map objects, and use `tmap_animate` to animate them.

Adding to your code above:

```
library(tmap)
library(gifski)

# sample osroute 50 times regularly, cast to POINT, return sf (not sfc) object
osroute_sampled <- st_sample(osroute, type = 'regular', size = 50) %>%
  st_cast('POINT') %>%
  st_as_sf() 


# use lapply to crate animation maps. taken from reference page:
#  https://mtennekes.github.io/tmap/reference/tmap_animation.html

m0 <- lapply(seq_along(1:nrow(osroute_sampled)), function(point){
  x <- osroute_sampled[point,]   ## bracketted subsetting to get only 1 point
  tm_shape(osroute) +            ## full route
    tm_sf() +
    tm_shape(data) +             ## markers for start/end points
    tm_markers() +
    tm_shape(x) +                ## single point
    tm_sf(col = 'red', size = 3)
})

# Render the animation
tmap_animation(m0, width = 300, height = 600, delay = 10)
```

It's been a while since I've used `tmap`, so I'm not up to date on adding provider tiles. Shouldn't be too hard for you to add those into the `lapply` function.
[image]

Comment: Thank you mrhellmann for replying to this post so quickly. I was wondering if you can also look at the followup of this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68908920/create-animation-of-vehicle-moving-along-a-route-with-timeline-of-events